# Ruby recursive function

Tags: ruby, function, recursion

I've problem returning value from recursive function.

```
def ask_question(question)
    print question
    answer = STDIN.gets.chomp

    ask_question question if answer.empty?
    return answer
end
```

The first time the **answer** is returned properly but I got empty string in next calls.
Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you aren't returning the value returned by your recursive calls to `ask_question`.

```
def ask_question(question)
    print question
    answer = STDIN.gets.chomp
    answer = ask_question question if answer.empty?
    return answer;
end
```

All you were doing is returning the first user input value (in your case an empty string) when the method was done.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because the variable `answer` you return it's always the one in the first iteration (each call has its own local scope). So a possible solution is:

```
def ask_question(question)
    print question
    answer = STDIN.gets.chomp
    answer.empty? ? ask_question(question) : answer
end
```

Note though that this recursive construction is fine with languages that support tail-call optimization, but Ruby does not force it, so it will usually create a new stack frame for each iteration and eventually it will blow. I'd recommend looping, for example:

```
def ask_question(question)
  loop do 
    print question
    answer = STDIN.gets.chomp
    break answer unless answer.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: To prove @tokland's point, if you run your program and hit enter a few times, then hit `ctrl+c` (for *nix), you'll see a stack trace proportionate to the number of times you hit enter.

Comment: good point, @jeremy. You can also run in a UNIX box "yes '' | ruby script.rb" and eventually get a "stack level too deep (SystemStackError)".