# How should I use recursive method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple web scrawler using Mechanize, now I'm stuck at how to get next page recursively, below is the code.

```
def self.generate_page  #generate a Mechainze page object,the first page
    agent = Mechanize.new
    url = "http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=intitle:#{URI.encode(WORD)}%20site:sina.com.cn&rn=50&gpc=stf#{URI.encode(TIME)}"
     page = agent.get(url)
     page  
end

def self.next_page(n_page)  #get next page recursively by click   next tag showed in each pages
 puts n_page   
# if I dont use puts , I get nothing , when using puts, I get 
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd341c70fd0>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd342f2ce08>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd341d0cf70>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd3424ff5c0>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd341e1f660>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd3425ec618>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd3433f3e28>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd3433a2410>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd342446ca0>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd343462490>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd341c2fe18>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd342d18040>
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007fd3432c76a8>  
#which are the results I want

    np = Mechanize.new.click(n_page.link_with(:text=>/next/)) unless n_page.link_with(:text=>/next/).nil?
     result = next_page(np) unless np.nil?
     result    # here the value is empty, I dont know what is worng
end

def  self.get_page  # trying to pass the result of next_page() method 
    puts  next_page(generate_page)
    # it seems result is never passed here, 
end
```

I followed these two links [What is recursion and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418017/what-is-recursion-and-how-does-it-work)
and [Ruby recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518233/ruby-recursive-function)
but still cant figure out what's wrong.. hope someone can help me out.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You shouldn't be calling `Mechanize.new` more than once.
2. From a stylistic perspective, you are doing too many nil checks.

Unless you have a preference for recursion, it'll probably be easier to do it iteratively.

To have your `next_page` method return an array containing every link page in the chain, you could write this:

```
# you should store the mechanize agent as a global variable
Agent = Mechanize.new

# a helper method to DRY up the code
def click_to_next_page(page)
  Agent.click(n_page.link_with(:text=>/next/))
end

# repeatedly visits next page until none exists
# returns all seen pages as an array
def get_all_next_pages(n_page)
   results = []
   np = click_to_next_page(n_page)
   results.push(np)
   until !np
     np = click_to_next_page(np)
     np && results.push(np)
   end
   results
end

# testing it out (i'm not actually running this)
base_url = "http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=intitle:#{URI.encode(WORD)}%20site:sina.com.cn&rn=50&gpc=stf#{URI.encode(TIME)}"
root_page = Agent.get(base_url)
next_pages = get_all_next_pages(root_page)
puts next_pages
```

Comment: Thanks!! at the first , I was going to do it iteratively, but failed at these lines :  `results.push(np)
   until !np
     np = click_to_next_page(np)
     np && results.push(np) `    your code really helped me a lot!